# How do you create a click function that changes html properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery to make click events. It is simple when I am changing css properties, but one of my elements I am trying to change (a canvas) the size in HTML.

I am trying to access and change this html code on a click - width and height:

```
 <canvas id="testCanvas" width="755" height="500" > </canvas>
```

with this jquery

```
 $('#flipthehood').click(function(){
   console.log('hood flipped clicked');
   $getElementById('testCanvas').animate({width="200"}, 250);   
 })
```

Is this the best way to go about it? if so, could I please have some advice with the syntax to make it work? I am getting an error of unexpected = sign

Thanks a lot

Comment: `{width="200"}` is not a valid JS object, you want `{width:"200"}`

Comment: Also, `$getElementById('testCanvas')` must be `$('#testCanvas')`

Comment: use `.css({})` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch element using id selector in jquery,

`document.getElementById('testCanvas')` is equivalent to `$('#testCanvas')`

and the correct syntax for `.animate()` is like:

```
$('#testCanvas').animate({width:"200"}, 250);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your click events are when the document is ready. Also document.getElementById isn't used in JQuery. This works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#flipthehood').click(function(){
        console.log('hood flipped clicked');
        $('#testCanvas').attr("width", "200");
    });
});
```

If you want it to be a smooth animation simply change it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#flipthehood').click(function(){
        console.log('hood flipped clicked');
        $('#testCanvas').animate({width: "200"}, 250);
    });
});
```

$.animate uses a colon instead of an equals sign.

Answer (score -1):

To change an element attribute with jQuery use the .attr() method:

`$("#testCanvas).attr("width", 200)`